# Join query on tables

Tags: mysql, join, indexing, entity-attribute-value

I'm running 2 queries on a table, both of them are the same in "Where" clause, so I beleive they should return same values.

My first query is:

```
select B.NameDastgahID, B.ZarfiateHamleBar, B.SherkateSazande, B.BisimHF, B.KanalBisimKhodroyi, B.ShomarePelak, B1.NameDastgahTitle, B2.NameKhodroTitle, B3.NoeKhodroTitle, B4.KarbarieKhodroTitle, B5.ShahreKhodroTitle, B6.cheraghgardanValue, B7.bisimHFTitle 
from dw.bohran_fct_etelaatenavegankhodroyi B
INNER JOIN dw.excel_dim_namedastgah B1 using (NameDastgahID) 
INNER JOIN dw.excel_dim_namekhodro B2 using (NameKhodroID) 
INNER JOIN dw.excel_dim_noekhodro B3 using (NoeNavganID) 
INNER JOIN dw.excel_dim_karbariekhodro B4 using (KarbariID) 
INNER JOIN dw.excel_dim_shahrekhodro B5 using (ShahrID)
INNER JOIN dw.excel_dim_cheraghgardan B6 using (CheraghGardan)
INNER JOIN dw.excel_dim_bisimhf B7 using (bisimHF)
where NameKhodroID = '630'
```

and it returns 61 rows.

The second query:

```
select *
from dw.bohran_fct_etelaatenavegankhodroyi 
where NameKhodroID = '630'
```

this returns 122 rows.

The second query always returns double rows than the first, even when I change the condition. Any idea??

Comment: In your second query, is your table name sooo long?

Comment: that was typed by mistake, I correct it, still same result.

Comment: Yet another reason why EAV schema is problematical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll suggest dropping one `JOIN` at a time, until you reach the one causing this.

This is not weird, its normal behavior , you are joining to 7 different tables, if any condition on all of this 7 tables will be incorrect , then the record would be filtered!

Comment: Thanks for your comment, it was useful. I understand joining with B1 and B5 cause the problem, but I still don't understand the reason!

Comment: @Naqme If `B1` and `B5` are causing the problem, it means `B1` doesn't have all of `B` `NameDastgahID`, and `B5` doesn't have all `B` `ShahrID`

Comment: Yeesss! After checking data I understand the problem. It was making me crazy, finally I could solve it. Thanks alot :)